# How to escape a single quote from a string in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a function that will accept a string from a parameter. From time to time I might receive a string that has a single quote and I need to escape it,

How can i escape a single quote from a string which was passed as a parameter in groovy?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: also please also include the context in which you need your variable escaped. Escaped to be printed on the console? Escaped to be pushed into a database? Escaped to be used as an argument to a shell process? Escaped to be evaluated as a string in your script somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i escape a single quote from a string which was passed as a
> parameter in groovy?

You could use `replaceAll` from `String`.

```
class StringEscaping {

    void process(String someString) {
        println someString.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def instance = new StringEscaping()

        instance.process "String With No Single Quotes"
        instance.process "String With Someone's Single Quote"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String With No Single Quotes
String With Someone\'s Single Quote
```

Comment: My answer assumes that by "escape" you mean prefix it with a backslash ("\").